# How to assign class to Columns 

Tags: html, css

I have like 100 rows, but I dont want to assign the class abc1,abc2,abc3,abc4 individually...

Is is possible to automatically assign the class to TD depending upont the column no i.e 
Column1  -- abc1
Column2 -- abc2
..etc

```
<Table>
 <tr class="odd">
   <td class="abc1"> ...</td>
   <td class="abc2"> ...</td>
   <td class="abc3"> ...</td>
   <td class="abc4"> ...</td>
 </tr>

<tr class="even">
   <td class="abc1"> ...</td>
   <td class="abc2"> ...</td>
   <td class="abc3"> ...</td>
   <td class="abc4"> ...</td>
 </tr>

<tr class="odd">
   <td class="abc1"> ...</td>
   <td class="abc2"> ...</td>
   <td class="abc3"> ...</td>
   <td class="abc4"> ...</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Hmm... Thanks for all the answers Guys.. Looks like there is no way to do it through CSS. Yes, I just added it to the server html.. but I was just looking if I can avoid that.

I dont want to do it with javascript.. Thanks for answers againg Guys!!!!!!!!

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Sounds like a job for JQuery.

Comment: if it is styling only, then CSS is enough

Comment: Do you need EACH of the rows to have a different style, or do you just need it to be odd/even?

Comment: @Kyle Noland has almost the right answer for you, below. Just output the class with the server side language (php, asp, etc.) that you are *already* using to output the table.

Comment: (And noticing that this question was edited, he may have answered the original question...)

Comment: yes, I got thr answer. Just added it to the server side.

Tanks Guys

RN

Answer (score 4):

Columns are actually supported in HTML and CSS using the `<colgroup>` and `<col>` tags: see http://htmldog.com/guides/htmladvanced/tables/
Add this at the begining of your table:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="class1" />
    <col class="class2" />
    <col class="class3" />
    <col class="class4" />
  </colgroup>
  ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with Javascript or a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) but, having gone down that road myself, I wouldn't. The reason is speed: I was doing odd-even row styling iwth jQuery and it was taking anywhere from 100-500ms to load the page (between that and a couple of other things). That is (imho) unacceptably long for something that can be done on the server.

If you're prepared to live with that, then go with that. CSS has an :nth-child(n) selector but that isn't supported in IE6.  Personally I would generate the classes as part of the HTML on the serverside.

With jQuery you could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("table tbody tr :first-child").addClass("abc1");
  $("table tbody tr :nth-child(2)").addClass("abc2");
  // etc
});
</script>
```

The advantage of jQuery is that it uses CSS2.1 and some CSS3 and custom selectors but it doesn't care about what the browser supports as it supports what the browser doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you want a cross-browser solution, but if support for Internet Explorer is not a problem then you can use the :nth-child rule. See [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild) and [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd). You could also do it with a JavaScript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is the col and colgroup xhtml tags.
Learn about them.

Also, there is:

```
#your-table tr td:first-child     //will target first td
#your-table tr td:first-child+td //will target the all the second td
#your-table tr td:first-child+td+td //will target the all the thired td
```

you get the drift

Comment: You should probably acknowledge that the second part doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: IE6? I do not develop for this antique

Answer (score 0):

Yes - if you are using a server side language like PHP or ASP.NET.  Here is the solution in PHP, assuming precisely 100 columns:

```
for( $i=0; $i < 100; $i++ )
{
    echo "<td class=\"abc$i\">your content here.</td>";
}
```

Since PHP will parse strings and insert the literal value of PHP variables, each iteration of this loop will increment your class by the value of $i, i.e. abc0, abc1, abc2 etc.

This will accomplish what you want.  However, I realize I have no idea what you are building, but I question the design decision which requires 100 columns, each of which must be styled differently.  I would be interested to see your final implementation.

KN